# Reads data from file. calculates on percentage and shows a table

Tags: c

So this code is not  yet completed. The end result has to calculate the average grade by each question. A=1 b=2 etc... and checks if the question is passed or not. 
this is what I got this far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROW 6
#define COLOMN 5


int input[ROW][COLOMN] , row, column;



int main(void)
{

float passedtests , returnedtests , percentage = (passedtest/returnedtest*100);
char filepath[100]= "" ;

//----- openen van extern bestand door middel van input van user.
FILE *inputfile;
printf("\n");
printf("enter path of file.\n");
scanf("%s", &filepathpath);
inputfile=fopen(filepath, "r" );

    if (inputfile == NULL){ printf("file not found."); }




fscanf(inputfile, "%f", &passedtests);
fscanf(inputfile, "%f", &returnedtests);



    for (row=0; row<ROW; row++)
       {
           for (colomn=0; column<COLUMN ; colomn++)
           {
                   fscanf(inputfile, "%d", &input[row][colomn]);
           }
       }



printf("passed tests: %0.f\n" , passedtests);
printf("Returned tests: %0.f\n" , returnedtests);
printf("Response is: %.1f %% \n\n" , percentage);
printf("   \t A\t B \t C \t D \t E \t grade \t comment\n\n");

for (row=0; row<ROW; row++)
 {
if (colomn==(COLOMN-1)) {printf("question %d  " ,row+1);}

            if (colomn==COLOMN) {printf("\n");}
                for (colomn=0; colomn<COLOMN ; colomn++)
                {
                    printf("%d  ", input[row][colomn]);

                }
 }
}
```

The output has to be like something like this:

```
number of passed tests: 20
Number of returned tests: 19
Response is 95%.
            A      B      C      D   E   grade     passed
question 1  2      2      2      2   2    2.4       yes
question 2  2      2      2      2   2    2.4       yes
question 3  2      2      2      2   2    2.4       yes
question 4  2      2      2      2   2    2.4       yes
question 5  2      2      2      2   2    2.4       yes
question 6  2      2      2      2   2    2.4       yes
```

So how far Am I ? I have made everything until calculating the average. Anyone got a good idea on how to do this ? Also I think the response variable is not good. Please check it out thank you !

btw the guys @ stackoverflow said to post code review here.

THE input file is like this:

```
20
19
1
2
4
5
7
0
1
8
7
3
8
5
4
2
0
2
2
4
11
0
2
3
3
5
6
0
0
4
12
3
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I would say this question is off-topic (as it's currently phrases) and that the people that sent you here from StackOverflow were wrong.  If you were to *only* ask us to review the code as it works currently (assuming it compiles which I didn't check), then I would consider that on-topic.

Comment: @syb0rg thanks for the input. I have found enough material from other posts to work it out better. I will post again if it's all done and working. (it works now but it's not totally finished.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many coding style issues here, that make this really hard to read.

- Inconsistent indentation throughout
- Too tightly packed expressions, for example:

  - Instead of `for (row=0; row<ROW; row++)`
  - This is easier to read: `for (row = 0; row < ROW; row++)`
- Code within `{...}` without line breaks, for example:

  - Instead of `if (column==(COLUMN-1)) {printf("vraag %d  " ,row+1);}`
  - This is easier to read:

    ```
    if (column == COLUMN - 1) {
        printf("vraag %d  ", row + 1);
    }
    ```

---

When you have two `if` conditions that will never be both true at the same time like this:

> ```
> if (column == COLUMN - 1) ...
> if (column == COLUMN) ...
> ```

That really should be written with an `else if`:

```
if (column == COLUMN - 1) ...
else if (column == COLUMN) ...
```

---

You opened a file with `fopen`,
but didn't close.
It's recommended to clean up any file handles opened by your program,
close them before you exit.

---

> ```
> inputbestand=fopen(bestandpad, "r" );
>
> //------ Boolean operator. Controle op geldigheid invoer.
> if (inputbestand == NULL){ printf("Bestand niet gevonden."); }
>
> //--inscannen eerste twee variablen,
> fscanf(inputbestand, "%f", &uitgereikt);
> ```

First of all,
the comment doesn't make any sense.
There's no "boolean operator" anywhere here.

But the bigger problem is that if opening the file fails,
the program simply continues execution as if nothing happened,
trying to read from a `NULL` file handle...

---

Instead of `printf("\n");`, I recommend `puts("");`.
It's shorter, simpler, faster.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I just began programming 2 weeks ago. But you got any idea on how to send a whole row to a new function so it can calculate the average ? and then sending it back ?